# Add text before the product Next Link in WooCommerce Composite products plugin

Tags: woocommerce, product, composite

I am using Woocommerce with WooCommerce Composite Products plugin.

Does anyone know how I'd add some text before the product "Next Link"?

I want to add a custom text before "Morning Workshop" at the bottom right or what ever other product I use, like "Next Step"…
Link to page: [Click here][1]

See screenshot below:

[![Screenshot][2]][2]

Comment: You should add in your question at minima a live link to your website composite product

Comment: Link added. Thanks